# Which Apollo Command Module is pictured here?

Tags: identify-this-object, capsule, museum-exhibits

I [recently requested help identifying](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43033/what-is-this-flying-boat-being-restored-at-the-udvar-hazy-center) what turned out to be a Sikorsky JRS-1 on Aviation.SE.  One of the comments in my post led to this follow up. In the same picture there is what I'm pretty certain is an Apollo command module:

[image]

As I mentioned in my previous post, I took this picture from the glass enclosed walk surrounding the restoration area at the Smithsonian Udvar Hazy Center in Dulles, Virginia.

I've seen the Apollo 11 Command module at the Washington D.C. Air and Space museum, so I'd have to guess this is a different one.  *Does anyone know?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this article](https://airandspace.si.edu/columbia-moves-virginia), the Apollo 11 CM was moved to Udvar-Hazy at the end of 2016.

As none of the other Apollo CMs seem to be there [according to this page](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/lunar/apolloloc.html), I would guess that is in fact [Columbia](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/command-module-apollo-11).

Comment: Right.  After a bit more searching, I came across [this](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/command-module-apollo-11) which confirms your answer.  I found this with a google search, for some reason I wasn't able to find it using the museum's search engine.